# on button click automatically remove selected spinner item

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

I have a spinner that show my array data list and delete button.
What I am trying to do is when I click on the delete button, it automatically deletes a selected spinner value, but I'm not certain how to do this.

In the delete button click function, deleted the selected spinner value after debugging my activity again but I want delete automatically a selected spinner value when I click on the delete button.

```
package quesansw.the1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class View1 extends Activity { 
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayAdapter adapter; 
    private String array_spinner[];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydatabase.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
        Window window = d1.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

        //d1.setTitle("Login");

        d1.setContentView(R.layout.view);
        d1.show();
        Button Click = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.Click);
        Button Save = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.Save);
        Button Delete = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.Delete);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from records", null);
        list.add("");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        /*array_spinner=new String[20];
        array_spinner[0]=list.get(0);*/
        Spinner s = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.toArray());

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);


        /*Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Spinner s = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);
                String str = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("********"+str);
                Cursor cur1=db.rawQuery("select * from records where tittle='"+str+"' ",null);
                cur1.moveToNext();
                String str1=cur1.getString(1);

                EditText ans = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.text);
                ans.setText(str1);

            }
            });*/

        Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Spinner s = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);
                String str = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                db.execSQL("delete from records where tittle='"+str+"' ");

            }
            });


        Click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Spinner s = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);
                String str = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("********"+str);
                Cursor cur1=db.rawQuery("select * from records where tittle='"+str+"' ",null);
                cur1.moveToNext();
                String str1=cur1.getString(1);

                EditText ans = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.text);
                ans.setText(str1);


            }
            });
    }
}
```

1) Here is my activity screen shot

[image: Activity Screen Shot]

2) Another screen shot with spinner values:

[image: Spinner Values]

Comment: Code, man, where's the code? We all know what a `Spinner` looks like but we don't know what's wrong with your code if we don't see what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

In deleteButton's onClickListener, remove the selected spinner value from the array data list and call onnotifydatasetChanges or again setSpinner adapter with the new array list after deletion.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Spinner spin;
Button delete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    delete  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    final ArrayList<String> spinneritems = new ArrayList<String>();

    spinneritems.add("item 1");
    spinneritems.add("item 2");
    spinneritems.add("item 3");
    spinneritems.add("item 4");
    spinneritems.add("item 5");


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinneritems );
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adp);

    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String selectedSpinner = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
            spinneritems.remove(selectedSpinner);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
}
```

Comment: You have to check for the case when there are no more spinner items left. I have added the values directly, you are just getting it from Sqlit DB.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring and initializing your `Spinner` so many times? Just do it once

```
public class View1 extends Activity { 
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayAdapter adapter; 
    private String array_spinner[];
    Spinner spinner;               // Declare your spinner here
```

then in `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydatabase.db",
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        spinner = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);  //initialize your spinner here

        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
```

then when you click `delete button` call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your `Array` and spinner

Comment: @sid123  You're welcome. I'm glad we were able to help. Please accept whichever answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

On delete button click listener add following code

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) d1.findViewById(R.id.tittle_spinner);
String str = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
adapter.remove(str);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
s.setSelection(0);
```